# Nginx install of Laravel app snipe-IT shows 404

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, http-status-code-404

After getting all the configs for `Snipe-IT` and `Larvel` etc. I am getting a 404 error when attempting to login.

There is no additional information. I've enabled 'debug' in my production app.php but no additional info comes out.

There's lots of issues reported and solved with Apache on this, require mod_rewrite to be installed.

Can't find anything for `Snipe-IT` and this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On searching Google in the morning (what a difference that makes) I found this using keywords for laravel and nginx:

http://laravel.io/forum/05-08-2014-nginx-laravel-routing-shows-404

The solution that worked for me was as given in the article, replace the "try files" with this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

Once I restarted Nginx, everything worked like a charm.